# pass directly the array as queryparams retrieving it with getAll using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, query-string

I take the id of items from this function, I want to send these id as an array and retrieving it with getAll()

```
    const queryParams: Record<string, string[]> = selectedItems.reduce(
      (acc, curr, index) => ({
        ...acc,
        ['item'] : curr.id
      }),
      {}
    );

    this.router.navigate(['/goToItems'], {
      queryParams
    });
```

I tried something like that but I didn't get an array. I want to create something like this:

```
  this.router.navigate(['/goToItems'], {
      item: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] // this array should be queryParams
    });
```

Please can you share with me any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be sent as the `queryParams` property. Try the following

```js
this.router.navigate(['/goToItems'], {
  queryParams: { item: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }
});
```

And fetch it in the recipient like so

```js
this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('item');
```